# Deploying war file in IBM Websphere Application server

Tags: websphere, war

I have created a web application and deployed it in IBM Websphere Application server.The application installs in the default folder with the default name 'WebApp_ID'.To run the app in browser, i am giving the server url/WebApp_ID.It runs fine.But i want to install another web application in the same server. I am not able to do it since it also installs in the same folder with the same name.

I have problems in changing the webapp name.My application does not contain geronimo-web.xml.Is there any way to change it using web.xml?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Give your war file a distinct name and then deploy.

**2)** You can also supply unique web-app id in your web.xml as below:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_1360725819438" metadata-complete="true" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Regards,